# How to redirect www to no-www on OpenShift properly?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, openshift, wsgi, no-www

I have an OpenShift Python app running on 730ne.cz and www.730ne.cz and I want the www version to redirect to the non-www.

I've added wsgi/.htaccess with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But that ended in infinite redirect loop too http://www.730ne.cz/application/application/application/application...

So I've tryed the following ones:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/ [R=301,L]
```

And:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.730ne.cz [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://730ne.cz/ [R=301,L]
```

And:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.730ne.cz
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://730ne.cz/ [R=301,L]
```

But all I get is this:

```
$ LANG=C wget http://www.730ne.cz/
--2015-03-12 21:40:13--  http://www.730ne.cz/
Resolving www.730ne.cz (www.730ne.cz)... 54.226.71.16
Connecting to www.730ne.cz (www.730ne.cz)|54.226.71.16|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.730ne.cz/ [following]
--2015-03-12 21:40:13--  http://www.730ne.cz/
Reusing existing connection to www.730ne.cz:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.730ne.cz/ [following]
--2015-03-12 21:40:13--  http://www.730ne.cz/
Reusing existing connection to www.730ne.cz:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.730ne.cz/ [following]
```

What am I doing wrong? How to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem with my [WordPress blog](http://www.subinsb.com) hosted on OpenShift and I fixed it with the following **.htaccess** rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subinsb.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://subinsb.com:80/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: On Python, I get redirected to http://730ne.cz/application/ but I can fix that by removing $1. Thanks

Comment: Actually no, with redirect to http://730ne.cz:80/ I still get redirected to http://730ne.cz/application

Comment: Did you add the www.730ne.cz in the custom domain section of App on Openshift ?

Comment: Yes, both 730ne.cz and www.730ne.cz

Comment: @hroncok But when I went to www.730ne.cz/ it redirects to http://730ne.cz/ without any problem.

Comment: Oh, really, so maybe it was in some cache before. Thanks